How do I redefine the css property @font-face?
Importing styles from an external library to index.html:
import 'outside-library/styles/main.css';

The main.css file contains custom fonts:
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Noto Sans';
    font-weight: 800;
    src: url('../assets/NotoSans-ExtraBold.ttf');
} 

Everything works fine, but ttf fonts have a large size. I want to redefine this font and upload it in woff/woff 2 format. I made a new css file in which I wrote:
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Noto Sans';
    font-weight: 800;
    src: url('../assets/NotoSans-ExtraBold.woff');
}

but wherever I connect a new file: before or after main.css, the browser still loads the ttf font. Is there any way to redefine @font-face?

What kind of external library just uses the TTF version ? in console, the woff file is loaded ? When you redefine the font-face, you are sure your CSS code is after the library CSS code ?

My understanding is that if you override a @font-face declaration, the font files from the original declaration and the override will both be loaded. One way you could prevent the TTF from being loaded is to delete it from your server. The browser will still request it, but will receive a tiny 404 response instead of the large TTF.

Are you sure your relative path is correct in the 2nd font-face rule?  Probably your relative path is not correct. Remove the remote lib css temporarily to test if your woff file is loading - then you should be able to override the fontface provided you load it after your main.css
